# EKS Cluster - No route to host - Private cluster

Tags: kubernetes

How do I connect to EKS private cluster from my laptop? I've enabled `endpoint_private_access`.

But I'm getting the following error. Could it be Security group issue?

`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.0.123:443: connect: no route to host`

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "main" {
  name      = var.eks_cluster_name
  role_arn  = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = concat(var.public_subnet_ids, var.private_subnet_ids)
    security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.eks_cluster.id, aws_security_group.eks_nodes.id, aws_security_group.external_access.id]
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = false
  }

  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Cluster handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EKS managed EC2 infrastructure such as Security Groups.

  depends_on = [
    "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.aws_eks_cluster_policy",
    "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.aws_eks_service_policy"
  ]
}
~
```

Comment: Using  `endpoint_private_access` the K8S/EKS API endpoint is attached to your VPC. It is not public. So your laptop must have a route to the VPC subnets. Alternatively you can use a jump host accessible from your laptop that is connected to a subnet in your VPC.